# How to implement aws api gateway into android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

So i deployed an api and imported the sdk into android. I tried to perform a simple GET method. Where I input a `userName` and it returns to me the user's `lastName`.

The lambda function (backend function) is called, so i am able to connect to it, but im not able to get the output.

Here is my class:

```
public class SampleGet extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        gatewayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cognito_gatewayButton);
        gatewayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                gateWayAsyncTask gateWayAsyncTask = new gateWayAsyncTask();
                gateWayAsyncTask.execute();

            }
        });
    }

    class gateWayAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        private String userName;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            //gateway
            creatingUser = clientFactory.build(MyUserClient.class);
            userName = creatingUser.rootGet("SampleUserName").getLastName;
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void var)
        {
            Log.d("gateway","gateway succeded!");
            if( userName == null)
            {
                Log.d("gateway","username is null");
            }
            else if(userName.equals(""))
            {
                Log.d("gateway","username is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("gateway",userName);
            }

        }
    }
```

In the sdk i generated from api gateway here is the client class:

```
@com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Service(endpoint = "https://ow2zhiry2b.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test5")

public interface MyUserClient {


    /**
     * A generic invoker to invoke any API Gateway endpoint.
     * @param request
     * @return ApiResponse
     */
    com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiResponse execute(com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiRequest request);

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @param username 
     * @return AndroidOutput
     */
    @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = "/", method = "GET")
    AndroidOutput rootGet(
            @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Parameter(name = "username", location = "query")
            String username);

}
```

Here is the AndroidOuput class which was also generated:

```
public class AndroidOutput {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("items")
    private String items = null;

    /**
     * Gets items
     *
     * @return items
     **/
    public String getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of items.
     *
     * @param items the new value
     */
    public void setItems(String items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

So the log that comes out is `username is null` and i have no idea why. I have checked the cloudwatch, and indeed my backend lambda function is running. And when i test the api in gateway it ran there. If anyone could please help me thatd be awesome!!

Comment: Can you run your API method via the test-invoke in the API Gateway console and post the body that it returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Retrofit and don't want to switch to AWS sdk, you may want to consider adding [AWS Gateway OkHttp Interceptor](https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor) to your `OkHttpClient`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using the [AWS Gateway for Android](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android)?

Comment: i dont need to use all of aws services only 5. But, ive done the aws tutorial walkthroughs, but none of them show what to do on the client side in android to get it working.